# Ignore parts when filtering with JQuery mobile

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile

I'm using an input field to filter data with JQuery mobile in the following way:

```
<input data-type="search" id="divOfPs-input">
<div data-filter="true" data-input="#divOfPs-input">
...
</div>
```

I would like to ignore some parts inside the div so the input doesn't take them into account.

For example if I have:

```
<input data-type="search" id="divOfPs-input">
<div data-filter="true" data-input="#divOfPs-input">
<label>Text</label> {anything}
</div>
```

I would like that the input ignores "Text". Is there any easy way to achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I answer myself. There is the attribute data-filtertext to specify what you want to filter with.

In my case:

```
<input data-type="search" id="divOfPs-input">
<div data-filter="true" data-input="#divOfPs-input" data-filtertext="{anything}">
<label>Text</label> {anything}
</div>
```